# What does $app['files'] do in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I came across this code `$app['files]` in a Laravel package.

I am just wondering what it does in Laravel.

Comment: run `dd($app['files']);` to see what it's outputting. Most likely, it's referencing the files in the laravel instance.

Comment: It is a piece of data in the $app array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$app['files']` refers to `\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem` as you can see in the doc [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades#facade-class-reference).

It's the same as accessing the `File` facade but in some places it's better to not use facades and access them with there bindings in the `$app` var
.